# Timezone on Time Datatype not working as expected - Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have model with an attribute (period_starting_at) of TIME datatype, running on Rails 5 with Postgres.

When my controller assigns a parameter value to that model attribute, something is changing the timezone to a wrong one. See the example:

```
model_one = Model.new

    puts params['Model']['period_starting_at'] #Returns 10:00

    puts Time.zone.parse(params['Model']['period_starting_at']) #Return 2018-07-16 10:00:00 -0300, which is with the correct timezone -3. 

    model_one.period_starting_at = Time.zone.parse(params['Model']['period_starting_at'])

    puts model_one.period_starting_at # Return 2000-01-01 10:00:00 -0200, which is with the **wrong** timezone -2.
```

The timezone of the rails app is correct.

`Time.zone.to_s` => "(GMT-03:00) Brasilia"

Also, the timezone of the database (postgres) is correct.

What am I missing?

Comment: What type of field is `period_starting_at`?

Comment: Its type text. I am using javascript to force the user to enter something like HH:MM.

Comment: if you're desperate, you can just `def period_starting_at; (super - 1.hour); end`

Comment: How are you setting Time.zone?

Comment: If `Model#period_starting_at` is a string/text, why are you parsing it into a `TimeWithZone`?

Comment: Also, I was unable to reproduce in a simple rails app: https://gitlab.com/snippets/1733951#note_88375694

Comment: @BM5k Thanks for the effort. Actually the type of `period_starting_at` is TIME. What I meant in the last comment is the type of the input in the HTML. That one is text. I think that way you be able to reproduce.

Comment: I'm having the same issue in fixtures. Setting a `time` column to `12:00:00 UTC` or `12:00:00 EDT` are both represented as `12:00:00` in the PostgreSQL column. The column type is `time without time zone`. On the other hand, setting the timezone on a datetime column works. This column type is `timestamp without time zone`.

Comment: Hi Richard! In my case, the problem was about DST - Daylight Saving Time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was about DST - Daylight Saving Time. Rails don't actually have a true 'Time' datatype, it's a 'Datetime' datatype with a dummy date part. But depending on the manipulation that you apply, that dummy date part can affect the timezome, because of DST. I hope I was helpfull.